# How to config spring to close ActiveMQ session or connection properly?

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

[image: ActiveMQ Producer]

A java producer uses spring connection pool to manage 100 MQ connections. Each MQ connection can open 500 sessions by default.

After 50000 messages produced, all the connections and sessions are used.

- It will be very slow, to get a new connection from the spring connection pool (get a connection from the pool first, then create a new session).
- And it will take quit a long time to close a connection.
- And the ActiveMQ server will use lots of memory.

I want to know:

- How to remove or reuse the sessions created by the connection?
- When to close a mq connection?

I have tried these parameters: idleTimeout + expiryTimeout + timeBetweenExpirationCheckMillis, but:

- When the system is very busy for a long time. The whole system will be slower and slower. The ActiveMQ will use more and more memory.
- When the system is very busy, then suddenly idle, then suddenly very busy. timeBetweenExpirationCheckMillis is not quick enough to close all the connections. The connection pool will try to close all the timeout connections(idleTimeout or expiryTimeout) and then open a new connection. The whole system will stuck for 10-20 mins.

I have tried to disable kahadb persistence, not working.

**Update1: ActiveMQ connection pool config**

```
<bean id="targetConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(tcp://activemq:61616)" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="targetConnectionFactory" />
  <property name="maxConnections" value="100" />
  <property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />
  <property name="expiryTimeout" value="60000" />
  <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="500" />
  <property name="timeBetweenExpirationCheckMillis" value="30000" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="10000"/>
</bean>
```

**Update2: Test code**

```
package just.a.test;

import javax.jms.Destination;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

@Component
public final class TestHandlerImpl{

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Destination testQueue;

    public void sendMessage(File binaryFile){
            //read file, get one msg
            JSONObject msg = processBinaryFile(binaryFile);

            //send msg to queue
            sendMessageToQueue(testQueue, msg.toString());
        }
    }

    protected void sendMessageToQueue(Destination destination, final String msg) {
        //this code will get one connection from pool
        //create a new session
        //and send the message
        jmsTemplate.send(destination, new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createTextMessage(msg);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Update3:**

Now, I have to modify activemq-all.jar and common-pool.jar to make the whole system to be stable.
Which I do not think is right.

Comment: Why is a single client using 50,000 sessions? Isn't one's enough?

Comment: Shouldnt it close the connection when it is finished with it, so open the connection to the queue send the message, close connection, the pool will keep it actually open and leave it in an open state for reuse, Let the pool actually close the connections, think of the close connection from the producer/consumers to be getfrompool() and releasetopool()

Comment: @user207421 Each time the app gets a connection from the pool, the connection pool will open one new session.  The code is in common-pool.jar.

Comment: @TheresaForster When the system is busy, the connection pool do not have a chance to close the connections. There will be more and more sessions, the ActiveMQ server will use more and more memory.

Comment: It says when to close the connection - answer as soon as it is used. as the pool keeps the real connection open but you want to release asap

Comment: @TheresaForster Sorry for the misleading title, I have changed it.

Comment: If you are using spring AMQP, it should abstract the logic of closing connection out from your end. Whenever the listener method completes, the channel will be returned to the pool to be used by other messages. Are you sure the consumer methods are completing in time ?

Comment: @Aditya Yes, I add some simple code. It is spring who manages the connection pool. But when the system is very busy, spring will not get a change to release the connections.  There will be more and more sessions, the ActiveMQ server will use more and more memory. I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: what are the stats of CPU and which process is taking much CPU?

Comment: @AmmarAli The CPU load is normal, but MQ server memory usage is high.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "system is very busy" ? Do you mean there are a lot of messages in queues ? The CPU and memory usage will be limited by the number of connections created. As long as the pool is limited, these stats will not spike. What is the volume you are looking at ? we regularly send 5k+ messages per second on a single connection to Rabbit MQ

Comment: @Aditya The producer will send 1K~2K messages per second. We use spring to manage the connection pool. The max connection number of connections of the connection pool is 100. There will be 20k messages in the queue.

Comment: The number of messages in the queue does not matter to the consumer. They will just be pulled at the rate that the consumption can handle. Are you producing and consuming together ?

Comment: @Aditya We have two services, one to produce messages, one to consume messages. They both work all the day.